# Where does the downloaded file go when execute robot framework using Jenkins

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, robotframework

I need one help,
I am Executing a script of robot framework using Jenkins, as per the flow the script should download one XLS and validate the data using Pandas.

When I am executing the script using Jenkins and searching the downloaded file in a hardcoded path i.e. "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads" the file is not found.
but when executing it manually the file downloaded on the same path

Can anyone please help me by telling me where do Jenkins stores all the downloaded files?

PS : I am using Google Chrome as web browser

Comment: Is Jenkins being run under a different user account?

Comment: @Ewong, Sorry but I am very new to Jenkins, Could you please let me know how to find that out. , I did not logged-in use any credentials

Comment: Can you show us how you download the file? What library do you use? Selenium or Browser library

Comment: I am just clicking on the export button on the web page and the file is getting downloaded

Answer (score 0):

For each job Jenkins runs, it creates a workspace directory, usually at:
`$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/(Name of the Job)`

The scripts (and robotframework's in this case) are run there, as the root directory. Most probably the downloaded file will be in a path from there (or an error should have occurred because the Jenkins user does not have access to the C:\Users... path).

There is a step in the Jenkins job, which is to archive (download) files from workspace, to Jenkins database, to be shown as "artifacts". Even the screenshots images or videos recording, must be registered in that step, so they can be viewed on the Report and Log in Jenkins (Robot Framework Plugin).